# Vuelidate: setting $model does not update component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuelidate

Given the following Vue component that uses Vuetify and Vuelidate:

```html
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <v-date-picker v-model="$v.picker.$model"></v-date-picker>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import { required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      picker: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)
    };
  },
  validations: {
    picker: {
      required
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

I would like to programmatically change the value of `this.picker`. I tried both changing the `v-model` as well as the Vuelidate `$model`:

```js
this.picker = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)
```

and

```js
this.$v.picker.$model = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10))
```

Neither of them caused a change in the UI nor produced an error message.

How can I programmatically update the DatePicker's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just assigning v-model to `picker` instead of `$v.picker.$model`.

You said you tried changing v-model, but this should work.

`<v-date-picker v-model="picker"></v-date-picker>`

Comment: I have file type input in my form that element can't use `v-model`. If you have any alternative solution. Kindly share it with me. @Josh Newlin

Comment: why does this work? vuelidate's documentation always uses the preceding $v and the following $model to the data point, yet, it seems that it has no purpose for the actual validation and it just introduces bugs.. anyone know what's the point of them?